# update component on click from another component

Tags: angular

I have shared service which contains property of class (which I want to share between two components)

```
@Injectable()
export class DetailsService {
    public detail: Detail;
    constructor() {}
}
```

in my component html I have this

```
<li *ngFor="let dt of data" (click)="DisplayData(dt)">
</li>
```

and in ts file

```
public DisplayData(dt: any){
    this.detailsService.detail = dt;
}
```

okay I'll inject it in me second component

```
constructor(private detailsService: DetailsService) {}
```

But then how can I display data in html? I can't do that in `ngOnInit` as it's not loading on page render. How can I catch that click and then display in html?

Comment: Please share your components/html for both parent and child, some information is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have an example with parent-child interaction, you have the link at the bottom of this answer.

You can very well add it to your ngOnInit. That is the good thing with shared service, the values is updated accordingly when you from either parent or child push/change new values to the service. As you can see from my plunker example they are both in parent and child placed in ngOnInit, in your case it would be:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.dt = this.detailService.detail;
}
```

You have bound this local variable to the variable in the service, so when changes happens in either the parent or the child the value gets updated. So when you have a click event in your parent, i.e:

```
public DisplayData(dt: any){
    this.detailsService.detail = dt;
}
```

you are pushing the new data to the service. The child component then catches that change automatically! If you refer to my example, you can see that.

It can be useful to add the elvis operator where you display your data in the view. And I think that is actually your main problem that you have stated in your question. How to do when there is not any data yet? Well, use the elvis-operator in the view and you are good :)

In your case it would be

```
{{dt?}}
```

This means that `dt` is not displayed unless it has a value! More about elvis-operator [here](http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/elvis-operator-in-angular-2.0)

Just in case you do not have an initial value in your shared object (or whatever) just remember to instantiate it in the service, so you don't get errors!

```
public detail: Detail = {};
```

Hope this helps! :)

### Simple example of [shared service](http://plnkr.co/edit/sff1lBSoRsBoIFWcXcTr?p=preview)